# react-beautiful-dnd - DroppableProvided > placeholder could not be found. - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I try to use "react-beautiful-dnd" and I got with the implementation into an existing project. The version of the package I'm using is 10.1.1 because I can't use a higher one.

I tried to place the placehoder in different divs and provided as well for droppable element.

```js
import React from 'react';
import SalesChart from './SalesChart';
import Tasks from './Tasks';
import LunchFeed from 'widgets/LunchFeed';
import Weather from 'widgets/Weather';
import {Draggable, Droppable, DragDropContext} from "react-beautiful-dnd";

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onDragEnd(result) {
        //TODO
        const {destination, source, draggableId} = result;
        console.log(result);

        if (!destination) {
            return;
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
                <Droppable droppableId="drop1">
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <div className="content" ref={provided.innerRef}  {...provided.droppableProps}>
                            <div className="container-fluid">


                                <div className="row">

                                    <Draggable key={1} draggableId={1} index={1}>

                                        {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                                <SalesChart innerRef={provided.innerRef}
                                                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}/>
                                            </div>
                                        )}

                                    </Draggable>

                                    <Draggable key={2} draggableId={2} index={2}>

                                        {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                                <Tasks innerRef={provided.innerRef}
                                                       {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                       {...provided.dragHandleProps}/>
                                            </div>

                                        )}

                                    </Draggable>


                                </div>

                                <div className="row">

                                    <Draggable key={3} draggableId={3} index={3}>

                                        {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                                <LunchFeed innerRef={provided.innerRef}
                                                           {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                           {...provided.dragHandleProps}/>
                                            </div>

                                        )}

                                    </Draggable>
                                    <Draggable key={4} draggableId={4} index={4}>

                                        {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                                <Weather innerRef={provided.innerRef}
                                                         {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                         {...provided.dragHandleProps}/>
                                            </div>
                                        )}

                                    </Draggable>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>

                    )}
                </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>
        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

I get the following warning when I drag an element around:
Droppable setup issue [droppableId: "drop1"]:DroppableProvided > placeholder could not be found.Please be sure to add the {provided.placeholder} React Node as a child of your Droppable.More information: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/droppable.md‍ This is a development only message. It will be removed in production builds.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, but I found in the documentation that you need to add the placeholder as a child of droppable & draggable.

Example:

```
<Draggable key={1} draggableId={1} index={1}>
    {(provided, snapshot) => (
        <div className="col-md-6">
             <SalesChart innerRef={provided.innerRef}
                         {...provided.draggableProps}
                         {...provided.dragHandleProps}/>
             {provided.placeholder}
        </div>
    )}
</Draggable>
```

Comment: Could you specify in which part of the documentation you found that you need a placeholder in the `<Draggable />`  component as well? On the project's GitHub, the `placeholder` is mentioned in the [`<Droppable />`](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/droppable.md#1-provided-droppableprovided)  component but nowhere in the [`<Draggable />`](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/draggable.md).

Comment: I did not find it again, perhaps it has changed. The truth was that I only was able to resolve the error adding the placeholder also in the draggable.  If you find any aditional info or you can remove the warning only adding the droppable placeholder let me know to change the answer.  Thanks ;)

Comment: I found that the `placeholder`  was required in the previous API of `Draggable` (before April 2018), see [this answer](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/8#issuecomment-379142374) from the project maintainer on the GitHub issue #8 of react `dnd`. This fix was merged on April 2018, see PR #406. The version 10.1.1 that OP mentions was released in mars 2019. So it's weird OP's issue was solved using this trick but glad it helped the community.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue locally.

You just need to inject the following code `{provided.placeholder}` at the end of the droppable container

e.g.

```
<Droppable droppableId="droppable-1">
  {(provided, snapshot) => (
    <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
      Good to go

      {provided.placeholder} // <- this is what you need 
    </div>
  )}
</Droppable>
```

Source: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/droppable.md#droppable-

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem with the use here [droppable.md](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/droppable.md).

you should use `{provided.placeholder}`

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have done everything described in the [documentation](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/droppable.md). I had the same problem and I had followed the documentation as well, but still was getting the same warning message. It finally worked for me when I paid attention to the document structure saw that **I had extra unrelated child element along with draggable and `{provided.placeholder}` inside droppable**.
For your case, using `<div className='row'>` instead of `<div className='content'>` for droppable props and ref properties may fix the warning.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers point out `{provided.placeholder}` is the solution, but please pay attention to add it to any `provided` you have, so in your case, you're using `Droppable` and `Draggable` and you should add `{provided.placeholder}` in both of them like below:

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
    <Droppable droppableId="drop1">
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <div className="content" ref={provided.innerRef}  {...provided.droppableProps}>
                <div className="container-fluid">

                    <div className="row">

                        <Draggable key={1} draggableId={1} index={1}>

                            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    
                                    {provided.placeholder} {/* <---- this one */}
                                </div>
                            )}

                        </Draggable>
                    </div>
                    {provided.placeholder} {/* <---- this one */}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </Droppable>
</DragDropContext>
```